# How to grep to matching multiple patterns with multiple options

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I need to filter a text file using grep with multiple patterns and multiple options:

```
grep -e "QUESTION" -e "Query" file.txt
```

this above works but I need to add some options like -A

```
grep -e -A3 "QUESTION" -e -A5 "Query" file.txt
```

Comment: `grep` does not support that. Write a custom program if you need that or run `grep` twice with different options

Comment: `grep` supports only single instance of Line Control

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in `awk` with a simple hack as `grep` does not support that.

```
awk -v var1=4 -v var2=6 '/QUESTION/{while (count<var1) line[NR+count] count++;} \
    /Query/{count=0;while (count<var2) line[NR+count] count++; }; NR in line' file.txt
```

Here the `awk` variables `var1` and `var2` control how much lines of text *including* the pattern needs to be printed. Similar to `grep` `-A` flags but with a value + 1.

You can see it working below for a sample file:-

```
$ cat file.txt
QUESTION
a
bc
c
d
e
f
Query
a1
bc2
c3
d4
e5
f5
foo
```

Running the command now with values `4` and `6`

```
$ awk -v var1=4 -v var2=6 '/QUESTION/{while (count<var1) line[NR+count] count++; } \
     /Query/{count=0;while (count<var2) line[NR+count] count++; }; NR in line' file.txt
QUESTION
a
bc
c
Query
a1
bc2
c3
d4
e5
```

This can be extended to any number of search patterns.

Answer (score 2):

#### By using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed '/QUESTION/{N;N;N;p};/Query/{N;N;N;N;N;p};d' file.txt
```

#### By using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$p=0;};$p=4if/QUESTION/;$p=6if/Query/;$p&&do{print;$p--}' file.txt
```

... But I prefer this:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{%search=("QUESTION"=>3,"Query"=>5);$p=0;$sre=join("|",keys%search);};
          $p=1+$search{$1}if/($sre)/;$p&&do{print;$p--}' file.txt
```

or

```
perl -ne '
    BEGIN{
        %search=(
            "QUESTION"=>3,
            "Query"=>5
        );
        $p=0;
        $sre=join("|",keys%search);
    };
    $p=1+$search{$1} if /($sre)/;
    $p && do { print; $p--: }
' file.txt
```

With this, you could easily add or remove search string with number of lines.

... Finally, just before creating a dedicated tool:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{ %search=@ARGV;@ARGV=();$sre=join("|",keys%search);};
        $p=1+$search{$1} if /($sre)/;$p&&do{print;$p--;}' <file.txt Query 5 QUESTION 3
```

#### By using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) V4.3 or higher:

```
( tee >(grep -A5 Query >&5) | grep -A3 QUESTION >&5) 5>&1 <file.txt | cat
```

or

```
command | ( tee >(grep -A3 Query >&5) | grep -A5 QUESTION >&5) 5>&1 | cat
```

Adding a last fifo seem reduce mixing problem...

Comment: Nota: Using `tee`  and *unnamed fifo* could mix randomely both output.

Comment: The last `cat` reduce mixing problem.